# python lotus notes: odbc connect error: source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, odbc, database-connection, lotus-notes, lotus

I am developing a client-server application for a cross-database system.

I am using Eclipse IDE with Python 2.5 and PyODBC2.5; need to read content from a Lotus Notes database, so run some basic query like - SELECT personname FROM tablename.

'import pyodbc' is ok - Python sees it!

But when I try to run:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Lotus NotesSQL Driver};SERVER=localhost;UID=John
Meyer;PWD=yellowbird;DATABASE=mydb.nsf")
```

it gives the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
[01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)
```

Any suggestions - what should be missing here? All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: PyODBC worked final at the end of the day. Just cant use alias for the odbc database. When using the real database name, it works nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost forgot to post the solution here...

We have managed to put NotesSQL to work through ODBC with python to access data from our Lotus Notes *.NSF files (database). It works as queries using the same type of queries syntax you would need normally use to get the data when working on MS-Access to grab the info inside the Lotus Notes *.nsf file.

So we got access to the data via SQL using ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's odd that you want to try accessing Lotus Notes data vie SQL. When I have interfaced Notes and Python in the past, I always used the Lotus Note COM object to access data. After all, Notes is a document database like CouchDB, not a relational database.